# adding usercontrol to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

The base class includes the field `'WebUserControl1'`, but its type `(common_WebUserControl)` is not compatible with the type of control `(ASP.common_webusercontrol_ascx)`

my code:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/LoginControl.ascx" TagName="TagLogin" TagPrefix="Login" %>


<Login:TagLogin id="CtrlLoginControl" runat="server"></Login:TagLogin>
```

wats wrong over here. wat i need to add any more...???

Comment: Do you have two classes named WebUserControl?

Comment: Something is wrong in the LoginControl.ascx itself. Please post its code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to place your controls in specific namespaces, then asp.net will not try to generate types for them.